Variation of Molar Conductivity
Consider 10 moles of X dissolved in 1 L solution, molarity 10M, and volume occupied by 1 mole of X is $\pu{100 cm3}$,  so molar conductivity of X is $k\times\pu{100cm^3}$, k being conductivity. So on increasing molarity volume associated with 1 mole of X decreases however molar conductivity increases overall because the loss is overcompensated by increase in k. Now if I dilute the solution by 0.5L water the volume associated with 1 mol of X obviously increases. I have learned that dilution initially increases the molar conductivity however the rate of this increase is slowly decreased.
My doubt is: I have read that dilution causes decrease in conductivity due to decrease in amount of charge carriers per unit volume, but increases conductance as the interference of ions with each other decreases leading to higher conductance(slowing down of ions is reduced), but where is this slowing down of ions factor included in the formula for conductance, isn't conductance given by conductivity x (concentration[from comment]) {or as i know [volume occupied by 1 mol of solute] times the conductivity} clearly this does not include how dilution provides free space for free movement of charge carriers.
So is molar conductance simply defined in terms of conductivity and concentration or does it include other terms which indicate this reduction in slowing down of ions upon dilution?

Note : I think molar conductance = (volume associated with 1 mol of
solute) * conductivity

I think i am, wrong as if(molar conductance)= volume occupied by 1 mole of solute * conductivity, then in case of infinite dilution, molar conductance would be infinite. I think the formula you have provided also results in the same conclusion as infinite dilution makes concentration 0 making molar conductance as infinity

is the formula (Λm=Λ0m−K√c) which defines molar conductance using conductance at infinite dilution arrived experimentally as in theory from the definition, conductance would be infinite at infinite dilution ?

$$\lim_{c \to 0} {G} = 0\tag{conductance}$$
$$\lim_{c \to 0} {\kappa} = \lim_{c \to 0} {\frac{G . l}{A}} = 0\tag{conductivity}$$
$$\lim_{c \to 0} {\Lambda} = \lim_{c \to 0} {\frac {\kappa}{c}} = \Lambda_0\tag{molar conductivity}$$
$$\Lambda = \Lambda_0 - k \sqrt{c} \tag{$\Lambda = f(c)$}$$
$$\kappa = \Lambda \cdot c = c \cdot (\Lambda_0 - k \sqrt{c})\tag{$\kappa = f(c)$}$$

hey, so i just have one final question, is the equation in  the fourth line of your answer used to find molar conductivity at infinite dilution as at infinite dilution molar conductivity cannot be found simply from conductivity as conductivity and concentration becomes zero  ?

Combine equations 3 and 4. Classical case for linear regression y = a + b.x, where x = sqrt(c).

makes sense now.

P.S.: There was intentionally omitted for simplicity the base conductance/conductivity of the water or other solvent undergoing self-dissociation.

Now i find my question silly, first off conductance(1/R) is measured experimentally, and conductivity is conductance per L/A, and molar conductivity as i have said is the product of conductivity and the volume associated with 1 mole of solute dissolved. Dilution obviously decreases molarity as it increases the amount of volume associated per mole, this increases conductance (k/C) so that's clear. Now conductance and conductivity are directly related, on dilution charge carriers per unit volume is decreased so conductivity decreases since it is measures experimentally and is affected by amount of charge carriers, i can say that dilution decreases conductivity, the increase and decrease are balanced to reach a maximum limiting value(dilution to reach this value is said to be 'infinite'). Now for infinite dilution equations given in poutnik's answer are used.

Note that multiplication by volume per $\pu{1 mol}$ (e.g. $\pu{0.1 L / mo}$l ) is equivalent to division by amount concentration ( e.g. $\pu{10 mol/L}$), as by definition,  $\Lambda = \dfrac {\kappa}{c}$. I personally see no reason why to go by the former way, as the parameter volume per mol is not useful elsewhere, in contrary to amount concentration.

i know the formula but, well, kappa is a constant, and i didn't know what to make of 1/c, so i just went by that definition to understand molar conductivity as the conductivity of 1 mole of solute

Kappa is conductivity. divided by amount concentration you get the molar conductivity. that is the standard approach. the alternative going for volume with 1 mol is highly unusual, but taught in some regions.
